# In Objective-C, is there an "extra" cost to using variable arguments lists in a recursive method?

Tags: objective-c, recursion, arguments

I just wrote this little extension method to make it easier to quickly sort arrays:

```
- (NSArray *)sortedArrayWithSpecialSortKeys:(NSString *)firstSortKey, ... {
    va_list args;
    va_start(args, firstSortKey);

    NSString *nextSortKey = va_arg(args, NSString*);

    va_end(args);

    if ([firstSortKey characterAtIndex:0] == '!') {
        firstSortKey = [firstSortKey substringFromIndex:1];
    }

    NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:firstSortKey ascending:YES];
    NSArray *newArray = [self sortedArrayUsingDescriptors:@[sortDescriptor]];

    if (nextSortKey)
        return [newArray sortedArrayWithSpecialSortKeys:nextSortKey, args, nil];

    return newArray;
}
```

Maybe this is a very dumb use of recursion, but my basic question really concerns any use of recursion in conjunction with variable-length arguments.

My question is: is this some sort of particular abuse of the argument list functionality provided by C, in the sense that it would be especially taxing or create a lot of "overhead" on the stack? Or is this, despite its awkwardness, basically okay?

Comment: Not sure about performance, but I would have chosen to pass an `NSMutableArray` rather than use varargs.

Comment: Yes, that makes a lot more sense, but I was trying to find a reason to test it out to see if it would work. It looks like it does, so I'm wondering (if maybe I ever found a good reason to use it) whether it would be any "worse" than recursion already is

Comment: I doubt it, but the stock answer here is to profile it against similar implementations.  And who can be ar$ed with that? :)

Comment: heh yes indeed. I'll do that but as I don't have much of a background in computer science I do feel a little bit lost when I can't begin to understand how the runtime would handle something like this

Comment: Did you test the code and it worked? Initially you pass strings. In the recursion you pass a `va_list`.

Comment: I tested it but only for one item now that I think about it - one sort descriptor that is